# xtick/ytick and \draw not agreeing on the scale used

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw an ellipsis with x radius 2 and y radius 1, inside a tikzpicture with a pgfplot. This is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ %inner axis line style={-latex},
                axis x line=center,
                axis y line=center,
                unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
                xmin=-1.6,
                xmax=3.2,
                ymin=-0.5,
                ymax=3.3,
                xtick={-1,0,1,2,3},
                ytick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7} ]
    \draw[black,thick]      (axis cs:1,2) ellipse [ x radius=2cm, y radius=1cm];
    \draw[fill,black,thick] (axis cs:1,2) circle  [ radius=0.02cm];
    \draw[dotted,thin] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:1,2) -- (axis cs:0,2);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

However, the result is not what I would like: looking at the ellipsis, we can see that the radii are not 2 and 1:

[image]

it looks like the scale used in the `xtick` and `ytick` axes and that used in the ellipse are different. Can I force them to be the same somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the `axis`, the environment is scaling the `x` and `y` vectors to generate the plot, so if you remove the `cm` specification on the `x radius` and `y radius` you get the desired results:

[image]

### Notes:

- You also need to specify at least version 1.5.1 via `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ %inner axis line style={-latex},
                axis x line=center,
                axis y line=center,
                unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
                xmin=-1.6,
                xmax=3.2,
                ymin=-0.5,
                ymax=3.3,
                xtick={-1,0,1,2,3},
                ytick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7} ]
    \draw[blue, ultra thick]      (axis cs:1,2) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=1];
    \draw[fill,red,thick] (axis cs:1,2) circle  [ radius=0.02];
    \draw[dotted,thin, gray] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:1,2) -- (axis cs:0,2);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-0.6)(3.85,3.9)
  \pnode(1,2){C}
  \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-1.5,-0.6)(3.5,3.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \psellipse(C)(2,1)
  \psdot(C)
  \psline[linestyle = dotted](0,2)(C)(1,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]